# Byte[] to BitmapImage in WP8 get exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, arrays, bitmapimage

I have web image, the url is correct since i can see it in web browser.

i read the web url into byte[] and convert the byte[] to BitmapImage.

but when debugger goes to "bitmapImage.SetSource(ms); " it goes to excetion:

```
StackTrace = "   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)\r\n   
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.BitmapSource_SetSource(BitmapSource bitmapSource, CValue& byteStream)\r\n   
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.SetSourceInternal(Stream streamSource)\r\n   at Sy...
```

in my CollectionHttpClient.cs

```
// get image from URL
        public static async Task<Byte[]> GetImageByImageName(string ImageName)
        {
            //Uri imageServerUril = new Uri(ImageName);

            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, ImageName);
            var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var responseData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            return responseData;

        }
```

in my view model

```
try
{
       ...........
byte[] imageByteArray = await CollectionHttpClient.GetImageByImageName(webImageUrl);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray))
                    {     
                        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                        bitmapImage.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;
                        bitmapImage.SetSource(ms); // exception occurs here
                        item.BitImage = bitmapImage;
                    }
     ............

}
catch(exception ex)
{
       ....
}
```

Comment: First - are you sure you get byte array as returned from GetImageBy...? Then if you are closing stream after the BitmapImage is created, you will probably have to set the CacheOption property to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad as [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx).